# to retrive data from database to bind with combobox

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

Script contains function which will increment row element defined in html

```
      <SCRIPT language="javascript">
      function addRow(tableID) {
        var rowNumber = document.getElementById('rowNumber');
        rowNumber.value = parseInt( rowNumber.value ) + 1;

        }
        </script>
```

Table consist of row that will be generated automatically by clicking add button .

I want to use value of P_Name[] and Make[] to retrive data from database to bind with  combobox Model[]

Error Obtained :- Notice: Undefined variable: Make in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\transaction1.php on line 117

Notice: Undefined variable: P_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\transaction1.php on line 117

```
         <TABLE id="dataTable"  border="1" cellspacing="10">
         <input id="rowNumber" type="hidden" name="row" value="1"/>
         <TR>
         <TD> 1 </TD>
         <td><SELECT name="P_Name[]" class="input_text">
                <option value="Camera">Camera</option>  
                  <option value="DVR">DVR</option>  
                   <option value="PS">Power supply</option>  
                    <option value="HD">Hard disk</option>  
                     <option value="wire">Wire</option>  
             </select>
         </td>
         <td> <select name="Make[]" class="input_text">
                  <option value="Electronic eye">Electronic eye</option>  
                   <option value="Viewmax">Viewmax</option>  
                   <option value="Hikvision">Hikvision</option>  
                   <option value="Sony">Sony</option>  
             </select></td>

             <TD> <?php 

              $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','danisco');   
                  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                     {
                       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                         }
                   else  {
               $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT p_model FROM product WHERE p_make = '$Make' AND p_name = '$P_Name' " );
                echo '<select name="Model[]" class="input_text">';
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
                       {  

                          echo '
                                <option value="'.$row['p_model'].'">'.$row['p_model'].'</option>
                                 ';

                   }
                  }
             ?>
             </TD> 
        <TD> <INPUT name="qty[]"type="text" /> </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT name="sno[]"type="text" /> </TD>



        </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <center><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable');"/>  </center>
        <label><span><b>Delivery Boy</b></span><input name="d_boy" class="input_text" type="text" size="20" />  
        <br><input type="submit" id="button1"/>
```

Comment: hey there is no one to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use j-query post function and withe php in different file.
It will be impossible to retrieve value of make and product.